# Imapsync doesn't recognize gmail older messages

Tags: email, gmail, imapsync

I am having an issue, i have synchronized my gmail account with another email. The sync process goes well.

The problem i am having is that imapsync doesn't recognize older messages. Right now messages from 3 April and before are not being recognized.

Do you think is a gmail issue, (for example gmail doesn't allow to see older messages through cli), or it might be a imapsync problem?

Here the command:

```
imapsync --host1 imap.gmail.com -user1 foo@gmail.com --password1 password1 --ssl1 --host2 imap.foo.com --user2 foo@foo.com --password2 password2  --ssl2  --folder [Gmail]/All\ messages
```

Even where i try with `--minage`, same story.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to encounter this issue on THIS account, it looks neither a Gmail nor an imapsync issue. I understand my answer seems foolish but each time a user reports this king of missing messages problem it always finish with "it was the wrong account" or similar. I can still be wrong but double-check what you see.

Comment: I am sure, i can see from gmail that i have 19.322 messages in the folder "All messages", all older messages from 3 April and before, when imapsync is executed, it doesn't show any messages in this folder.

Comment: Gmail has also a configuration part where folders can be imap exported or not, check that too. Send me the log with option --justfoldersizes